# my java program is giving me a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, string, runtime-error

```
public static boolean isValidDate(String date) {
    int firstSlash, lastSlash, ddlnt, mmlnt, yylnt;
    int[] Days = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
    boolean dateValid = true;
    String mlnt;
    firstSlash = date.indexOf("/");
    lastSlash = date.indexOf("/");
    ddlnt = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(0, firstSlash));
    mmlnt = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(firstSlash + 1, lastSlash));
    yylnt = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(lastSlash + 1));
    if ((ddlnt == 0) || (mmlnt == 0) || (yylnt == 0))
        dateValid = false;
    else if (mmlnt > 12)
        dateValid = false;
    else if ((ddlnt == 29)
            && (mmlnt == 2)
            && ((((yylnt % 4 == 0) && (yylnt % 100 != 0) || (yylnt % 400 == 0)))))
        dateValid = true;
    else if (ddlnt > Days[mmlnt - 1])
        dateValid = false;
    return dateValid;
}
```

This is an small piece of code from a project I am working on that when its run produces the following error

```
J:\>java Text5 2 A 0 11/10/1995 11/12/1995
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String ind
ex out of range: -1
        at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
        at Text5.isValidDate(Text5.java:142)
        at Text5.ValidDate(Text5.java:117)
        at Text5.ArgumentCheck(Text5.java:84)
        at Text5.main(Text5.java:19)

J:\>
```

line 142 is this:

```
 mmlnt = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(firstSlash+1,lastSlash));
```

this part of the code receives a string with a date ie. "11/10/1995".Its job is to just check that its a valid date.The rest of the program runs fine just this part crashes it

Comment: Wouldn't `firstSlash` and `lastSlash` be the same?

Comment: `indexOf` always returns the first occurrence.

Comment: I think you want: `lastSlash = date.lastIndexOf("/");`

Comment: Oh yeah thanks thats it.I forgot to change it to last index

Comment: Check what happens if the indexOf operations return -1, indicating the string is not contained at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error in lastSlash since firstSlash and lastSlash both have same value

**public int indexOf(int ch): Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified character or -1 if the character does not occur.**

this line **mmlnt = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(firstSlash + 1, lastSlash));** gives you error ..

since **lastSlash < firstSlash + 1**